# How to stop a parent div expanding vertically when child div becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a parent div that has a height set on it.

There are child divs inside of it with initial visibility turned off.

When I make it visible, the parent div expands vertically. I dont want that.

Background:

I'm using DataTables, with the scroller and filterColumn plugins.
The header of my table has an action on it assigned by jQuery that when I click on the a column header, a div is to appear below it and show some content.
Issue is, when it appears, the header div expands.

I've tried overflow: hidden, auto, etc, but the closest i can get is the scrolling body seems to cover the floating div. I also set the z-index to above the scroller, but that doesnt do anything either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: div { max-height: 200px !important; }

Comment: overflow:hidden works with floats I think

Comment: can you show it in a  fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can give the parent div a fixed height

```
.parent {
    height: 400px; 
 }
```

and make your child div have absolute position

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position:absolute` on the element being shown to remove it from the page's flow. this will prevent it from affecting the width of the parent div.